# Melting data for ggplot with repeat observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a figure in qqplot and ran into numerous limitations given my improper data structure.  I have been learning `melt` with modest successes, but hit a wall earlier today and thus the post...

Here are my data:

```
Data <- structure(list(IndID = 1:21, Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), class = "factor"), ObsVal = c(1.41284403669725, 
1.62790697674419, 1.75, 1.66666666666667, 2.43870967741935, 1.44827586206897, 
1.14925373134328, 1.97492163009404, 1.3202846975089, 2.16176470588235, 
1.04347826086957, 0.886075949367089, 1.07142857142857, 1.70588235294118, 
0.736842105263158, 0.92831541218638, 2.3489932885906, 1.19298245614035, 
1.77333333333333, 1.5092936802974, 1.09375), PredOne = c(1.79816513761468, 
1.69302325581395, 1.3125, 1.66666666666667, 1.58064516129032, 
1.49655172413793, 1.35820895522388, 1.75548589341693, 1.54448398576512, 
2.26470588235294, 0.971014492753623, 0.974683544303797, 1.19642857142857, 
1.14705882352941, 0.7, 0.92831541218638, 1.69127516778523, 1.63157894736842, 
1.58666666666667, 0.936802973977695, 1.3125), PredOneSE = c(0.223991010436964, 
0.157266749617986, 0.26685283856462, 0.279490729147869, 0.217964053891366, 
0.183190936591734, 0.247680519057338, 0.139883305737923, 0.138095727169982, 
0.229908170921439, 0.0958135248131566, 0.119418717242245, 0.110103432730496, 
0.147639754039624, 0.126097806088354, 0.115507093629184, 0.181420305238205, 
0.0996366549877819, 0.247829674731325, 0.121267372297112, 0.305724781523581
), PredTwo = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.68965517241379, 
1.37010676156584, 1.95588235294118, 1.21739130434783, 1.04113924050633, 
1.16071428571429, 1.79411764705882, 0.921052631578947, 1.07885304659498, 
1.59731543624161, 1.15789473684211, 1.4, 0.884758364312268, 1.09375
), PredTwoSE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.139757218234836, 
0.139437440563685, 0.230049935329134, 0.100384450568462, 0.120136555331195, 
0.108827344413171, 0.160200199902538, 0.129061017287195, 0.118592278416655, 
0.181692974138931, 0.10539741014593, 0.250638082175034, 0.116275618418844, 
0.328923912088501), PredThree = c(1.15596330275229, 1.5953488372093, 
1.3125, 1.44444444444444, 1.4, 1.30344827586207, 1.25373134328358, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.50335570469799, 1.05263157894737, 
1.30666666666667, 0.83271375464684, 1.09375), PredThreeSE = c(0.217917157594837, 
0.156690895211124, 0.265747120521213, 0.283879122849779, 0.211186596624607, 
0.185731296470196, 0.250576068630065, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.182610106475943, 0.104015282782907, 0.251314706554144, 
0.115476874855973, 0.326509616387012), PredFour = c(1.92660550458716, 
1.72558139534884, 1.53125, 1.66666666666667, 2.21290322580645, 
1.5448275862069, 1.46268656716418, 1.8871473354232, 1.54448398576512, 
2.47058823529412, 1.34782608695652, 1.15189873417722, 1.30357142857143, 
2, 1.03157894736842, 1.17921146953405, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PredFourSE = c(0.220294176796081, 
0.15685192799583, 0.203552293443519, 0.282184484298284, 0.232052930820242, 
0.18341190292051, 0.245852887002432, 0.13924415405254, 0.13892122505451, 
0.226280189300754, 0.100441922715917, 0.124327614845589, 0.108785137191018, 
0.16032552882793, 0.12815531922484, 0.117223056201348, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("IndID", "Area", "ObsVal", "PredOne", 
"PredOneSE", "PredTwo", "PredTwoSE", "PredThree", "PredThreeSE", 
"PredFour", "PredFourSE"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 
24L, 25L, 26L), class = "data.frame")
```

The head of which looks like this

```
IndID Area   ObsVal  PredOne PredOneSE PredTwo PredTwoSE PredThree PredThreeSE PredFour
1     1  AAA 1.412844 1.798165 0.2239910      NA        NA  1.155963   0.2179172 1.926606
2     2  AAA 1.627907 1.693023 0.1572667      NA        NA  1.595349   0.1566909 1.725581
3     3  AAA 1.750000 1.312500 0.2668528      NA        NA  1.312500   0.2657471 1.531250
4     4  AAA 1.666667 1.666667 0.2794907      NA        NA  1.444444   0.2838791 1.666667
5     5  AAA 2.438710 1.580645 0.2179641      NA        NA  1.400000   0.2111866 2.212903
6     6  AAA 1.448276 1.496552 0.1831909      NA        NA  1.303448   0.1857313 1.544828
  PredFourSE
1  0.2202942
2  0.1568519
3  0.2035523
4  0.2821845
5  0.2320529
6  0.1834119
```

I have 21 individuals (IndID 1:21) across three different areas (AAA:CCC). For each individual there is an observed value and four different predictions,each of which has an SE.  In some instances, there are no (NA) prediction or SE (this is on purpose).

With the code below (ugly and long I know!):

```
#Make the columns with NA numeric
Data$PredTwo<- as.numeric(Data$PredTwo)
Data$PredThree<- as.numeric(Data$PredThree)
Data$PredFour<- as.numeric(Data$PredFour)
Data$PredOneSE<- as.numeric(Data$PredOneSE)
Data$PredTwoSE<- as.numeric(Data$PredTwoSE)
Data$PredThreeSE<- as.numeric(Data$PredThreeSE)

#Make figure
DataFig <- ggplot(Data)+                                                
  geom_point(aes(x=factor(IndID), y=PredOne, color=Area),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymin=PredOne-PredOneSE, ymax=PredOne+PredOneSE, color=Area), width=.4, lty = 1, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=PredTwo), color = "red", size=3,shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymin=PredTwo-PredTwoSE, ymax=PredTwo+PredTwoSE, ),width=.4, color = "red", lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=PredThree),color = "blue", size=3,shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymin=PredThree-PredThreeSE, ymax=PredThree+PredThreeSE),width=.4, color = "blue", lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=PredFour),color = "darkgreen", size=3,shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymin=PredFour-PredFourSE, ymax=PredFour+PredFourSE),width=.4, color = "darkgreen", lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=ObsVal, color = Area), size=14,shape="*")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","darkgreen"),labs(fill="Study\n Area"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))
DataFig
```

I can produce the following figure:

[image]

While this is close to what I want, the poor data structure leaves me with limitations. I am trying to:
1) include `linetype` as an `aes()` argument so they can be included in a legend.  I want PredOne to have a solid line and PredTwo : PredFour to have dotted lines.

2) `dodge` the points and error bars so that they are not overlapping. For each Area there are three Predictions.  I am trying to get PredOne (the solid line) as the center and the two other predictions for each Area `dodge`-d to the right and left.

I posted a similar question yesterday, [that can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368619/manually-changing-linetype-order-and-offsetting-error-bars-in-ggplot), but cannot correctly apply the (very helpful) suggestions by @Henrik to a larger data set with more estimates.

Any suggestions on how to salvage the above code, or more effectively use `melt`would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, regarding data structure, you have to use melt twice:

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- melt(Data,id=1:3, measure=c(4,6,8,10))
d2 <- melt(Data,id=1:3, measure=c(5,7,9,11))

data.melt = data.frame(d1,se=d2[[5]])
head(data.melt)
#   IndID Area   ObsVal variable    value        se
# 1     1  AAA 1.412844  PredOne 1.798165 0.2239910
# 2     2  AAA 1.627907  PredOne 1.693023 0.1572667
# 3     3  AAA 1.750000  PredOne 1.312500 0.2668528
# 4     4  AAA 1.666667  PredOne 1.666667 0.2794907
# 5     5  AAA 2.438710  PredOne 1.580645 0.2179641
# 6     6  AAA 1.448276  PredOne 1.496552 0.1831909
```

This gives you a data frame with a column, `variable` that identifies the type of prediction (`PredOne` to `PredFour`), and has separate columns for the value and se.

Regarding the second part, you can come close with just this:

```
ggplot(data.melt) +
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=ObsVal), size=3)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=value, color=Area))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymax=value+se, ymin=value-se, 
                    color=Area, linetype=variable), width=.5 )+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,2,2))
```

[image]

This doesn't have the error bars dodged, but with this many ID's, dodging creates an extremely busy and confusing plot. I'd urge you to consider faceting instead:

```
  ggplot(data.melt) +
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=ObsVal), size=3)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=value, color=Area))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID, ymax=value+se, ymin=value-se, color=Area), 
                width=.5 )+
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

[image]

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

So this deos what you want, I think. The basic idea is to add a dodge column and use it to offset the aesthetic mapping for x.

```
data.melt$dodge <- 0
data.melt[data.melt$variable=="PredTwo",]$dodge=-0.2
data.melt[data.melt$variable=="PredThree",]$dodge=+0.2
data.melt[data.melt$variable=="PredFour",]$dodge=-0.2
data.melt[data.melt$variable=="PredFour" & data.melt$Area=="BBB",]$dodge=+0.2
ggplot(data.melt) +
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID, y=ObsVal), size=3)+
  geom_point(aes(x=IndID+dodge, y=value, color=Area))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=IndID+dodge, ymax=value+se, ymin=value-se, 
                    color=Area, linetype=variable), width=.1)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,2,2))+
  facet_wrap(~Area,scales="free",ncol=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(data.melt$IndID))
```

[image]

Comment: @jihoward thanks for the suggestions on melt and also the use of facet_grid which is a new ggplot function for me!  Faceting is a good approach, although I need to facet by Area, thus the dodging is still a necessary step. Thanks!

Comment: @jlhward.  Thanks for your continued suggestions!  I was waking through your code with my real data in which IndID is a factor than a seg of 1:n and cannot simply add dodge to IndID (IndID+dodge).  That being said, I should be able to code a work around and then change the labels on the figure. Thanks again!