# Dodge-ing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this data

```
Data <- structure(list(StudyArea = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", 
"CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), Obs = c(190L, 481L, 219L, 190L, 
481L, 219L, 190L, 481L, 219L), InSituPred = c(180, 462, 199, 
180, 462, 199, 180, 462, 199), InSituSE = c(9.57382456553708, 
16.5306359391421, 9.51070020039693, 9.57382456553708, 16.5306359391421, 
9.51070020039693, 9.57382456553708, 16.5306359391421, 9.51070020039693
), variable = c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituAAA", "ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", 
"ExSituBBB", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC", "ExSituCCC", "ExSituCCC"
), value = c(NA, 500, 172, 156, NA, 161, 200, 562, NA), SE = c(20.8552264204181, 
16.1382421185167, 21.43693858142, 20.8552264204181, 16.1382421185167, 
21.43693858142, 20.8552264204181, 16.1382421185167, 21.43693858142
)), .Names = c("StudyArea", "Obs", "InSituPred", "InSituSE", 
"variable", "value", "SE"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which look like this

```
StudyArea Obs InSituPred  InSituSE  variable value       SE id
1       AAA 190        180  9.573825 ExSituAAA    NA 20.85523  1
2       BBB 481        462 16.530636 ExSituAAA   500 16.13824  2
3       CCC 219        199  9.510700 ExSituAAA   172 21.43694  3
4       AAA 190        180  9.573825 ExSituBBB   156 20.85523  1
5       BBB 481        462 16.530636 ExSituBBB    NA 16.13824  2
6       CCC 219        199  9.510700 ExSituBBB   161 21.43694  3
```

and this code

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.4)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=StudyArea))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1,position=dodge)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable),position=dodge, lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea ), lty=1,cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12)

p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen","red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
```

I can create this plot
[image: fig]

I want to `dodge` the dotted lines on either side of the solid line like is currently done in StudyArea BBB.  Following the helpful comments from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368619/manually-changing-linetype-order-and-offsetting-error-bars-in-ggplot) I have tried to add unique column for each value in the `variable` column, but the `dodge`-ing will not change.

Suggestions for how to make StudyArea AAA and CCC look like BBB (i.e. centered solid line and right and left dotted lines) would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you mean you want to shift them horizontally, not vertically?

Comment: Yes, shift them horizontally (left and right), NOT vertically.

Comment: You will have to dodge them manually. ggplot is consistently dodging them based on `variable` (`ExSituAAA` to the left, `ExSituBBB` in the center, `ExSituCCC` to the right), but you want to dodge them based on similarity to `StudyArea` (don't dodge if the same, dodge one way or another if not) and there is no way to specify that type of thing in `ggplot`. Creating another column which is 0 if they are the same and +0.2 or -0.2 if not and then setting the `x` aesthetic to something like `as.numeric(factor(StudyArea))+offset.column`. Or just figure out the horizontal positions for each set.

Comment: @BrianDiggs, Thanks for the helpful comments.  Adding a new column worked perfect for the error bar, but not for the point.  I added `x=as.numeric(factor(StudyArea))+id` to the error bar `aes` which dodged correctly.  However, when I added the same code to the `geom_point` I get the following error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.  I can edit my original post to add more details if need be.  Thoughts?

Comment: Just from your description of the new problem, I don't have any suggestions. I would ask a new question rather than edit this one, though, because what is wrong is different (even though you are still trying to get to the same point).